# Can we talk about the set of real valued functions without specifying a domain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Can we talk about the set of real valued functions without specifying a domain?

Is the collection of all functions a set?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, A real valued function is a SET of ordered pairs (a,b) with b$\in R$ no 2 of which have the same first member . Each function has a domain and a range (or image) which is also a set . However if you do not limit the possible domains ,the collection of of these functions is not a set . If you limit yourself to say functions whose domains lie in a given set M ,for example M = n dimensional Euclidean space $R^n$ then the collection of all such functions is a set . 
  If you use a set theory which includes classes which are not sets (sets are also classes) then the collection of all functions is always a class which is not a set .Note that in class-set theory , the members of a class is always a set .

Comment: There are a couple of statements in this answer that aren't universally true but they are true for the 'set theories' and 'class theories' you probably have in mind. It's not really relevant to OP's question but note that there are class theories that allow proper classes as elements of other classes (of higher order) and that there are set theories in which the set of all real valued functions exists (i.e. this collection is a set). Basically: You are unnecessarily broad in your statements and consequently wrong in inessential ways.

Comment: I don't doubt any of your remarks .I had in mind Kelly-Moore class-set theory and its more conservative sub-theories  like Zermelo-Fraenkel , Von Neumann-Berneys-Godel that working mathematics uses . I discard theories like Quines New Foundations and other theories that are not compatible with these and never used by workers in classical mathematics .Thank You for your remarks though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one speaks about such things in terms of a *contravariant functor* (a.k.a. *presheaf*, or in this particular case, a *sheaf*).

$\mathcal{C}$ is a contravariant functor from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$. Among other things, this means that for any topological space $X$, $\mathcal{C}(X)$ is the set of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Working with $\mathcal{C}$ itself, rather than its value at a particular topological space, is in some sense like working with all such sets of functions at once, or alternatively working with the set of functions on an indeterminate space.

Being a functor, it actually has some more structure (namely, how functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ compose with continuous functions $Y \to X$) that makes it more amenable to study than simply talking about all of the sets of functions.

(Note if the codomain isn't fixed, we use $\mathcal{C}(X, Y)$  to denote the continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$)